# How to use class methods without useing "type": "module" in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

js developer.
I am making express and jade web app. Now I am trying to call class method in `index.router.js` from `login.controller.js`, I have been looking for a way to call the method without adding `"type": "module"` in package.json. This is because my teacher said I should avoid using it for now. I have been looking for a solution for this, but I haven't figured out how. Thanks for reading!

Here's my code:

```js
//This is index.route.js

const express = require('express');
const app     = express();
const IndexRouter  = express.Router();
const LoginController = require('../controllers/login.controller')

IndexRouter.use('/', LoginController.login())

module.exports = IndexRouter
```

```js
//This is login.controller.js

module.exports = class LoginController{
    async login (req,res) {
        res.send("Login Page")
    }
}
```

Comment: `class` syntax has nothing to do with modules.

Comment: Your mistake is that you're not instantiating the class anywhere. But really, why use `class` at all? Just write `module.exports.login = async function(…) { … };` and it would work

Comment: @Bergi must the OP instantiate the class to use a class method?  How about declaring login as `static`?

Comment: @danh I'm not saying they should, but the way the `class` currently is written, one would expect them to do it.

Comment: I see, @Bergi. To the OP: if all that class does is provide a static method, you'd be just as well off dispensing with the class and exporting login as a function.  If it's really going to be a class with state and other methods (and I hope so), then fix by declaring your login method like this `static async login(....`

Answer (score 0):

1. Create [Class Objects](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_classes.asp) and use class objects to access class
   methods

   In index.route.js

   ```
   const express = require('express');
   const app = express();
   const IndexRouter = express.Router();
   const LoginController = require('../controllers/login.controller')
   const loginController = new LoginController();
   IndexRouter.use('/', loginController.login())

   module.exports = IndexRouter
   ```

   In login.controller.js

   ```
   class LoginController {
       async login(req, res) {
           res.send("Login Page")
       }
   }

   module.exports = LoginController;
   ```

   For Ex.

   ```js
       class LoginController {
           login(req, res) {
               console.log("LoginController Login");
           }
       }

       const loginController = new LoginController();
       loginController.login();
   ```
2. Or can directly access Login function without using class

   In index.route.js

   ```
   const express = require('express');
   const app = express();
   const IndexRouter = express.Router();
   const { login } = require('../controllers/login.controller')
   IndexRouter.use('/', login()); // or use('/', login) if using middleware

   module.exports = IndexRouter
   ```

   In login.controller.js

   ```
   async function login(req, res) {
       res.send("Login Page")
   }

   module.exports = {
       login
   };
   ```